# How can i get more than 7 fields in domain filter odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, erp, odoo-12

here is the code ,it's filtering 7 fields i need more than 7 how to achive it. Please my indentations

```
class sem(models.Model):
_name = 'module4_sem'
_rec_name = 'id'

sem_no = fields.Char("Semester No")

class Semester(models.Model):
_name = 'module4_semester'
_description = 'semester info'

cou = fields.Many2one('module4_course',"Course")
sem_tot = fields.Integer(related = 'cou.sem_no',string = "Total Semester")
sem_no = fields.Many2one('module4_sem',string="Semester no")



@api.onchange('sem_tot')
def sem_count(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.sem_no = False
        s = self.env['module4_sem'].sudo().search([('id','<=',rec.sem_tot)])

        return {'domain':{'sem_no':[('id','in',s.ids)]}}
```

Comment: Please explain your need, what do you achieve using ('id','<=',rec.sem_tot). Bit confusing,

Comment: It is better if you explain what do you want to achieve and what is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@api.onchange('sem_tot')
def sem_count(self):
    model = self.env['module4_sem'].sudo()
    s_ids = []
    for rec in self:
        rec.sem_no = False
        s = model.search([('id', '<=', rec.sem_tot)])
        s_ids.extend(s.ids)

    return {'domain':{'sem_no': [('id', 'in', s_ids)]}}
```

Comment: The [onchange method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/api.py#L171) is invoked on a pseudo-record that contains the values present in the form. You do not need to loop over `self`.

Comment: Not true. Onchange is a function that can be called when you need it, on multiple recordset, too. A good practice is to loop ever self.

Comment: It is from Odoo documentation. In your, example did you call it or it is called when the value of `sem_tot` is changed? I would like to know where you found that it is a good practice to loop over self. For which record you return the domain!

Comment: Try this code without a loop and tell me what happen:

self.env['YOUR.CLASS'].search(DOMAIN).sem_count()

Comment: You can do this

Comment: Read my comment again, we are not talking about the same thing.